# selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element by name

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying for selenium to click on the 'See all followers' button in the Company Admin page in LinkedIn.
However the above error code at the bottom comes up.

I have even switched to an frame, however the problem is persisting.

Code:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

browser = webdriver.Chrome('driver/chromedriver.exe')

browser.get('https://www.linkedin.com/login')

file = open('config.txt')
lines = file.readlines()
username = lines[0]
password = lines[1]

elementID = browser.find_element_by_id('username')
elementID.send_keys(username)

elementID = browser.find_element_by_id('password')
elementID.send_keys(password)

elementID.submit()

visitingProfileID = '/company/13643283/admin/analytics/followers/'
fulllink = 'https://www.linkedin.com/' + '/company/13643283/admin/analytics/followers/'
browser.get(fulllink)

submit_button = browser.switch_to.frame(browser.find_element_by_name('See all followers'))
submit_button.click()
```

Error:

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[name="See all followers"]"}

Adding image:
[image: See all followers]

Comment: Where is `See all followers` in that admin page ? I could not locate one

Comment: Attaching image for better view. It is inside the All followers card.

Comment: Have you written the code to reach till here ?

Comment: So, basically after I have logged in and routed to my all followers page, I get the See all followers button inside the All Followers card view.

Comment: okay I guess you have a different access. Nevertheless share HTML code for `See all followers` and the iframe that you have mentioned

Comment: submit_button = browser.switch_to.frame(browser.find_element_by_name('See all followers'))
submit_button.click()

Comment: I asked for HTML

Comment: <button class="org-view-page-followers-module__modal-button t-16 p1 t-bold full-width" type="button"> See all followers</button>

Comment: and in which frame does this button reside ? please share HTML.. all you have to do is right click and select copy

Comment: Yes. Yes it does.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232797/discussion-between-daremitsu-and-cruisepandey).

Answer (score 0):

As I see, the unique locator for that button is `org-view-page-followers-module__modal-button` class.
So you can locate it by any of the following:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('org-view-page-followers-module__modal-button').click()
driver.find_element_by_css_locator('.org-view-page-followers-module__modal-button').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[contains(@class,'org-view-page-followers-module__modal-button')]).click()
```

Comment: Unfortunately, for all three, the same error is coming.

Comment: Maybe you need to add some delay / wait before clicking the element?